# Screen share shared audio issue while using snaps

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, snap, 21.10, budgie

Experiencing an issue on Signal and Zoom snaps. Running Ubuntu Budgie 21.10.

During the screen share there is no sound from my shared desktop. I have tried signal .deb - no screen share sound, no mic input sound no sound from the other side.

On snap I only have screen share sound missing.

Specs:

```
snap    2.54.3+21.10.1ubuntu0.2
snapd   2.54.3+21.10.1ubuntu0.2
series  16
ubuntu  21.10
kernel  5.13.0-30-generic

System:    Host: budgietux Kernel: 5.13.0-30-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Budgie 10.5.3 
           Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-30-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E5470 v: N/A serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0VHKV0 v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.25.3 
           date: 03/19/2021 
CPU:       Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-6300U bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache: L2: 3 MiB 
           Speed: 500 MHz min/max: 400/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 500 2: 500 3: 500 4: 500 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Started thining recently that maybe it is an pulseaudio issue.

Any ideas how to approach the issue and get it solved?

EDIT:

While playing around with `pavucontrol` found out that my mic input gets patched into internal mic device under recording and screenshare sound gets patched into my Bluetooth headphones mic channel.

How to get both inputs active in `pulseaudio` during the screen share?

Comment: Did you enabled such permissions for each snap?

Comment: I checked in gsettings. Everything, pertaining to the situation in both of apps, is enabled.